# UIList View Shows Cells only once their out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been working through [this tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-index-list-uitableview/) and I can get the cell info to show up but only if the that particular cell is out of the view. For example, the bottom three cells load just find because they are bellow the "fold" and I have to scroll to get to them. Once I scroll down, the top cells appear.  New to objective-c so I'm not really even sure where to even begin. Can you someone point me in the right direction?

[What it looks like after scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmrq1.jpg)

```
 #import "agendaController.h"

@implementation agendaController{

    NSDictionary *schedule;
    NSArray *scheduleSectionTitles;

}

- (IBAction)goBack:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{



}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Will be JSON from web
    schedule = @{@"Monday, February 6th" : @[@"6:15 p.m. VIP ticket access",
                                             @"6:30 p.m. Doors open",
                                             @"7:00 p.m. General Session 1"
                                             ],
                @"Tuesday, February 7th" : @[
                                            @"9:30 a.m. VIP ticket access",
                                            @"9:45 a.m. Doors open",
                                            @"10 a.m. General Session 2",
                                            @"6:15 p.m. VIP ticket access",
                                            @"6:30 p.m. Doors open",
                                            @"7:00 p.m. General Session 3"
                                            ],
                @"Wednesday, February 8th" : @[
                                            @"9:30 a.m. VIP ticket access",
                                            @"9:45 a.m. Doors open",
                                            @"10 a.m. General Session 4",
                                            @"9:45 a.m. Doors open",
                                            @"9:30 a.m. VIP ticket access",
                                            @"7:00 p.m. General Session 5 (Baptisms immediately following service)"
                                            ]
                 };

    scheduleSectionTitles = [[schedule allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];


}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [scheduleSectionTitles count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [scheduleSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *sectionTitle = [scheduleSectionTitles objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *sectionSchedule = [schedule objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    return [sectionSchedule count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [scheduleSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [schedule objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *prepschedule = [sectionAnimals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = prepschedule;



    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //Configure cell
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you put the cell creation code at the wrong place:

- When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, you will only get back cells

  - that you have created before and
  - that are currently being scrolled out of view (e.g. invisible because lower than the bottom / higher than the top of the table).
- Therefore, the first some dequeue calls will simply return `nil`, because there is nothing to be dequeued.
- Now you try to configure the *non-existing* cell and set its text. In Objective C, a call (message) to `nil` does not crash, but simply does nothing. This is even harder to debug, though.
- At the very end, you check if the cell is `nil`, and if, then create a new one and return this new (non-configured) cell.
- Once you scroll around, there are cells to be dequeued (because they have been scrolled out of view), which then will be reused and configured and now you start to see your data.

---

The solution is to **rearrange** your code and put the cell creation directly after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register the cell prototype and use a newer dequeue method to get rid of the nil verification. It will always return a dequeued cell properly resized.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Configure the cell...
    NSString *sectionTitle = [scheduleSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionAnimals = [schedule objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *prepschedule = [sectionAnimals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = prepschedule;


    //Configure cell
    return cell;
}
```